# Tracing errors in Laravel Artisan Command

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to convert some http endpoint to console endpoints and have trouble tracing errors. Given command (simplified):

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Console\Controllers\TaskController;

class DummyCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'dummy';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        TaskController::make()->perform(...);        

    }
}
```

If I insert an error perhaps `$z["break me"];` in handle() the console outputs

> In DummyCommand.php line 42:                            Undefined
>   variable: z

Just as expected. Also If I put it in TaskController::make() it points to the correct file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Controllers;

class TaskController
{

    public static function make() {
        return new TaskController();
    }

    public function perform($tasks) {
        return $tasks->map(function($task) use($tasks) {
            return $this->feedback($task, $tasks);
        });
    }

    private function feedback($task, $tasks) {
        try {
            $taskClassName = '\\App\\Stimpack\\Tasks\\' . $task->name;
            $task = new $taskClassName( $tasks);
            $feedback = $task->perform();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            abort(500, $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $feedback;
    }     
}
```

However as you can see the TaskController resolves class names on the fly so the execution continues in other files. If there is an error in these files I get a not so helpful error message refering to Application.php:

> In Application.php line 940:                           Undefined
>   variable: z

Why does this happen?

Is there a way for me to get a more specific location from the error message?

Comment: Instead of `abort(500, $e->getMessage());`, you need to get the trace. Try dumping the  `$e` with `dd($e)`, and see if the information you need is there. If so, you could send the information you need in the `catch` block,

Comment: Thanks Felippe, that did the trick!!